# Which is more memory efficient, SQLite database or XML string[]?

Tags: android, arrays, string, sqlite, memory

I'm new but learning. I just need to know, which is more memory efficient, string[] in xml or an SQLite db? I can do either, and can do pre-populated on the db. I'm talking about at most 1000 strings, with more possible in updates.

Thanks for your answers.

PS I have learned so much from Stackoverflow. this is the first place I turn to when I hit a snag. Thank you.

Comment: This is the wrong question to ask. A better question to as is "what approach [better] solves this problem"? They are three *entirely different things* suited to *different purposes*. SQLite is a database. XML is a structured document encoding. string[] is just an array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say string[] is much better. Here is a good answer from SO itself.

"Unless you want to store the data persistently I'd say you should probably just use an Array. Databases are more for persistent storage (i.e. stuff you'll need over multiple runs of your app). That said, if you arrays start getting reeeeeeeeeealy* big, then yea you're going to want to move them onto disk (in which case they won't take up any memory). And probably the simplest way to do that is with a database.

*On the order of magnitude of hundreds of thousands of entrys, maybe even more."
Source: @Kurtis Nusbaum
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7906472/847954

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the strings are and what you need them for. If they vary each time the app runs, leaving them in memory, as a string array, is probably best. If they are persistent between app runs, the sqlite DB will probably be better in the long run since you don't need to "reload" the database between app runs.

Likewise, do you really need all 1000 strings in memory at all times while the app runs? If so, again the array might be a good idea. If not, the database is a better bet.

Ultimately, you need to run it on a variety of android devices and see which implementation is sufficiently responsive for whatever the app is designed to do.